# Google Analytics API java lib - certificate error

Tags: java, ssl, google-analytics-api

I am using [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client#Service_Accounts) java library to extract GA data. But it is generating the following certificate error:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I verified that it is trying to establish connection with url https://lhr26s05-in-f13.1e100.net which outputs a certificate error when accessed through the browser. I'm surprised this is happening as this is a google owned domain.

I have tried to manually download the certificate and add it to the cacerts file but that didn't work.

I have also tried to trust the certificate like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868167/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatorexception) which has worked on other projects, but not for this one. I wonder if this is not working because I am using the google api java libraries? I'm out of ideas and would appreciate any suggestions